# Easy way to modify incoming filter value from Sharepoint List?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, performancepoint

Does anybody have a quick and dirty solution for this?

I have a Sharepoint List Filter with values like:

**Information Technology**

**Accounting**

**Human Resources**

etc.

The filter values need to be sent to both a Sharepoint List web part and a Performance Point chart.  The SP list web part can take the values as they are, and filter the list, but PPS needs brackets around the values with multiple words, e.g. **[Information Technology]** and **[Human Resources]**.

Recommendations on how to modify the incoming value to PPS chart?  Or something slicker?

Thanks!

Marc

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I misunderstand your question, but I recently did something similar by adding an extra column to the SharePoint list with the "[Member]" as the value and "Member" as the key and then just send the value columns to the PPS report.